# Android Recyclerview Update (Example = Gmail Read Change font )

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Android recyclerview item click event after update Recyclerview

Image description here

[image]

Mail 1  READ 
Mail 2 Dont Read

In the item the click event I want to do this to me
How can you help make

```
  public class Mesajlar_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Mesajlar_Adapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Mesajlar> resultModels;
    private Context context;
    public Mesajlar_Adapter(List<Mesajlar> resultModels, Context context) {
        this.resultModels = resultModels;
        this.context = context;

    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mesajlar_listview_desing, parent, false);
        ViewHolder view_holder = new ViewHolder(v);


        return view_holder;

    }
    public void resetList() {
        int size = this.resultModels.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                resultModels.remove(0);
            }

            this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }

    }


    public void addItem(Mesajlar item){
        this.resultModels.add(item);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        holder.mesaj_id.setText(resultModels.get(position).getMESAJ_ID());
        holder.kullanici_id.setText(resultModels.get(position).getKULLANICI());
        holder.gelen_detay.setText(resultModels.get(position).getDETAY());
        holder.kategori.setText(resultModels.get(position).getKATEGORI());
        holder.konu.setText(resultModels.get(position).getKONU());
        holder.tarih.setText(resultModels.get(position).getKAYIT_TARIHI());

        String a = resultModels.get(position).getOKUNDU();
        holder.okunma.setText(a);


        if (a.equals("Hayir")){

            holder.kategori.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.kategori.setTextSize(19);
            holder.konu.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.konu.setTextSize(19);
            holder.tarih.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        protected TextView mesaj_id;
        protected TextView kullanici_id;
        protected TextView gelen_detay;
        protected TextView konu;
        protected TextView kategori;
        protected TextView tarih;
        protected CheckBox secim;
        protected TextView okunma;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.okunma =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.okunma);
            this.mesaj_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mesaj_id);
            this.kullanici_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kullanici_id);
            this.gelen_detay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gelen_detay);
            this.konu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Konu);
            this.kategori = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Kategori);
            this.tarih = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Tarih);
         //   this.secim = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.secim);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(context, Mesaj_Detay_Activity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            String detay = gelen_detay.getText().toString();
            String mesajid = mesaj_id.getText().toString();
            String kullaniciid = kullanici_id.getText().toString();

            i.putExtra("detay", detay);
            i.putExtra("mesaj_id",mesajid);
            i.putExtra("kullanici_id",kullaniciid);
            context.startActivity(i);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add this interface for click event

```
public interface OnRecyclerItemViewClickListener {
  void onClicked(int position, Mesajlar jar);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Mesajlar {
    ...
    boolean isClicked;

    public boolean isClicked() {
        return icClicked;
    }

    public void setClicked(boolean isClicked) {
        this.isClicked = isClicked;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Adapter**

```
private OnRecyclerItemViewClickListener listener;

public Mesajlar_Adapter(List<Mesajlar> resultModels, Context context, OnRecyclerItemViewClickListener listener) {
    ...
    this.listener = listener;
}

...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (resultModels.get(position).isClicked()) {
        // change pressed background color here!
    } else {
        // change default background color here!
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
      listener.onClicked(position, resultModels.get(position));
    });
...
}
```

**Activity**

When you create RecyclerView Adapter, add OnRecyclerItemViewClickListener to constructor of adapter in Activity

```
Mesajlar_Adapter adapter = new Mesajlar_Adapter(list, context, new OnRecyclerItemViewClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClicked(int position, Mesajlar jar) {
        jar.setClicked(true);
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Mesaj_Detay_Activity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("detay", jar.getDETAY());
        i.putExtra("mesaj_id",jar.getMESAJ_ID());
        i.putExtra("kullanici_id", jar.getKULLANICI());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling click event in adapter level you can use interface and do it in activity level. Pass the adapter position to the activity, from activity you can do the actual process

see the sample http://wiki.workassis.com/android-recyclerview-example/